# Check if Column is empty

Tags: .net, database, vb.net, ms-access

I am looking on how to check the column data of a specific row. I found this:

```
For Each row In tablePiglet.Rows ' - data table
        If Not DBNull.Value.Equals(row("CurrentLocation")) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Not Empty")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Empty")
        End If
    Next
```

I tried to run the app, and the code does not execute. I added a breakpoint in `For Each` but it just ended. Why is that? There had been yet a data on CurrentLocation field, so it should display empty.

What I want is to check whether that row's `CurrentLocation` is empty or not.
Something like : `SELECT CurrentLocation FROM tableFoo WHERE id=1` then check if its empty or not.
Is the code above the right thing to do? Or are there other better ways?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    For Each _dtrow as DataRow In tablePiglet.Rows ' - data table
        If _dtrow.Item("CurrentLocation").toString IsNot Nothing Or
           _dtrow.Item("CurrentLocation").toString <> vbNullString Then

              MessageBox.Show("Not Empty")
        Else
              MessageBox.Show("Empty")

        End If
    Next
```

Comment: The code is spot on right? Is there something I did wrong? Field name is okay, but still, it does not execute. Break point doesn't go to `If` statement.

Comment: no its not wrong.. its incomplete.. you must assign your **ROW** as **DATAROW** since its bounded in datatable.. and **take note** don't use **ROW** as a variable name because it might be a reserved word... you must name it uniquely... so my answer is not working?

Comment: I totally get that, sadly, it doesn't go through the condition statement.

Comment: I've tried many variations, but still, I think it does not recognize the data Table. But it should throw an exception if a data table is not existent, but its not.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that you only have a single row, and you know it because in your db only one row may have a certain id as you pointed here

```
SELECT CurrentLocation FROM tableFoo WHERE id=1
```

In this case you don't need to loop, you KNOW, this is a single row

```
If tablePiglet.Rows.Count > 0 Then
    If IsDbNull(tablePiglet.Rows(0)("CurrentLocation")) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Empty")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Not Empty")
    End If
End If
```

That should do it

But if you do have many rows, ok, create List

```
Dim l as new List(of String)

For i as integer = 0 in tablePiglet.Rows.count-1

 If IsDbNull(tablePiglet.Rows(i)("CurrentLocation")) Then 
     l.Add(i.ToString())
 end if
next

if l.Count > 0 Then MessageBox.Show("Empty rows are " & string.Join(",", l.ToArray())
```

It will list all the rows with empty "CurrentLocation"

Comment: I just used that sql statement for you guys to get what I was looking for through coding. But eventually, I will need an ID because I need to compare "some" to `CurrentLocation`. Error says, *There is no Row at position 0*. Is it because Data Table is not populated? But I tested my DGV and its showing data, so the dataTable should've been loaded. **EDIT**:now it compiles, still, does not show msgBox. :/

Comment: This is why I added check if you have rows. When I re-read your question, I realized that your issue probably lack of data because your code would work. Bad but working

Comment: okay, I added an `Else` "no rows". Worked fine. But why doesn't it get the rows? I have three at the moment..

Comment: Check your query. Check your loading. The reason I don't like your initial code is because if you have few rows, you going to be bombarded with message boxes

Comment: Well, I just thought of using `For Each` because that's the thing I used to get/set data from the database. Its better for SO to see some code that I tried instead of nothing. Anyway, your updated code, does not seem to get the rows. its null "Empty rows are ". I don't really get why the app doesn't recognize the data table. Its like data table is non-existent

Comment: This because I forgot to turn `tablePiglet.Rows(0)` into `tablePiglet.Rows(i)` . Check the updated code. Like I said, my answer is based on provided info. You don't have here code that shows how you retrieve the rows

Answer (score 0):

maybe try this .... i use `as Datagridviewrow`

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In xDataGridView.Rows

   If row.Cells("CurrentLocation").Value Is Nothing Or row.Cells("CurrentLocation").Value Is DBNull.Value Then
       MessageBox.Show("Not Empty")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Empty")
   End If
Next
```

edi: my bad didn't see it was on dt

but your code is right so something else must be messing with it

edit2: you said, that the for each ended right away ...
 my guess is its empty did you check the counts on it?

Comment: well, that's easier, but I can't use a DGV for this particular part. I need to customize it, so I cannot bind it.